# SQL Server : join on two columns using substring

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables:

**Table A**:

```
colA  
----
NY  
CA  
NJ  
AZ  
USA
```

**Table B**:

```
colB  
-----
CA  
AZ  
USA - LA  
USA - NC  
USA
```

I want to join colA to colB and produce the following results:

```
CA  
AZ  
USA  
USA  
USA
```

I am thinking of joining the 2 columns using substring but how do you account for the 2-letter values(CA, AZ...) while matching 'USA' which is more than 2 letters.

I wasn't able to find any answers in the existing posts.  Feel free to redirect.  Also, feel free to modify the title.

Comment: Something like this would do the join although performance would probably suffer. `from tablea inner join tableb on tablea.cola = left(tableb3colb,3)`. If there are only 2 characters in `colb` then only 2 are returned, if there are 3 or more then 3 are returned.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
DECLARE @T1 TABLE(data VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @T1 VALUES('NY'),('CA'),('NJ'),('AZ'),('USA')

DECLARE @T2 TABLE(data VARCHAR(10))
INSERT INTO @T2 VALUES('CA'),('AZ'),('USA - LA '),('USA - NC'),('USA')

SELECT t1.*
FROM @T1 t1
INNER JOIN @T2 t2 ON t1.data = LEFT(t2.data,LEN(t1.data))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can as the below:

```
SELECT
    A.colA
FROM
    TableA A INNER JOIN 
    TableB B ON '-' + REPLACE(B.data, ' ', '') + '-' LIKE '%-' + A.colA + '-%'
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do the join although performance might suffer. If there are only 2 characters in `colb` then only 2 are returned, if there are 3 or more then 3 are returned.

```
-- stage test data
DECLARE @tablea AS table(cola VARCHAR(3))
DECLARE @tableb AS table(colb VARCHAR(8))

INSERT INTO @tablea (cola) VALUES ('NY'),('CA')  ,('NJ')  ,('AZ')  ,('USA') 
INSERT INTO @tableb (colb) VALUES ('CA')  ,('AZ')  ,('USA - LA')  ,('USA - NC')  ,('USA')

-- Query
SELECT cola
FROM @tablea 
INNER JOIN @tableb ON cola = LEFT(colb,3)
```